# How should I add a new button outside prototype TableCell, not inside?

Tags: ios, uitableview

***Background***

I am trying to create an App which allows people to share their favorite recipes. I got stuck on the "new recipe" page. This page is a scrollable table. The first part is a container view where I put all static contents (recipe image, recipe name). The second part is the ingredient section where displays the name of ingredients. The third part is where people describe the recipe step-by-step.

***Question***

I've been trying to create an "Add" button, so users can dynamically add a new ingredient (because we don't know how many ingredients beforehand). However, it seems impossible to set constraints for this button on Storyboard. I don't want this add button put within the cell (there would be one button for each row in this case). I am trying to put the button right after the last row.

I've been researching a bit but not much progress. Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first make sure `ingredient` and `recipe step-by-step` different section.

now in `ingredient` section total number of `ingredient` + one row extra that extra row put your button.

*For example*

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
      return ingredient.count + 1
    }
   //do staff
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == ingredient.count - 2 {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: addbuttonCellId, for: indexPath) as! AddbuttonCell
      //do your staff 
       return cell
      }

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ingredientCellId, for: indexPath) as! IngredientCell
      //do staff 
      return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the sketch is a row. Ingredient name is a row. Ingredient 2 name is a row. Step by step instruction is a row. Okay, so Add is a row. You just need another type of prototype cell that contains just an Add button, and in your data source (`cellForRowAt:`), make sure it appears in the correct place.